# Ratio of folded isosceles triangle area

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area, origami

Take an isosceles triangle with legs length $1$ and base angle $\theta$. Take the apex and move it to a leg vertex. Describe the ratio of the new folded shape's area to its previous as a function of $\theta$, and determine the domain of $\theta$ for which this is operation is possible.

[image: Folding process]

In my efforts, I've solved the ratio to be $1+\frac1 4\sec2\theta$, but I can't find and prove any strict bound. I know $\pi/3\le\theta$ since it will fold over exactly at that point, and obviously $\theta<\pi/2$, but I think there may be a stricter bound.

Comment: Consider [Huzita-Hatori axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huzita%E2%80%93Hatori_axioms). What do you know about the point between the apex and the right-sided vertex and the projecting lines?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
$$\begin{gathered}
  A = \frac{1}{2}{1^2}\sin \left( {180^\circ  - 2\vartheta } \right) = \frac{1}{2}\sin 2\vartheta  \hfill \\
  A' = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}1h = \frac{1}{8}\tan 2\vartheta  \hfill \\
  h = \frac{1}{2}\left|\tan \left( {180^\circ  - 2\vartheta } \right)\right| > 0 \to 90^\circ  > \vartheta  > 45^\circ  \hfill \\
  \frac{{A'}}{A} = \frac{{\frac{1}{8}\left|\tan 2\vartheta \right|}}{{\frac{1}{2}\sin 2\vartheta }} = \frac{1}{4}\left|\sec 2\vartheta\right|  \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$
The base angle must be larger than $45°$ otherwise you have an obtuse angle in the vertex and your folding goes out of the original triangle

Comment: Why do you think the minimum angle must be 45, and what is the upper bound for the angle? It can be shown that 45 degrees is not possible, and I think the minimum is 60 degrees (equilateral triangle folds exactly), but I cannot find an upper bound for theta.

Comment: Is it possible to fold the triangle twice and get a new one, similar to the original and with area equal to 1/3 of the original area? It doesn't have to be isosceles.